# Interrogation about the lost update transaction isolation issue

Tags: transactions, isolation-level, acid, transaction-isolation

I have an interrogation about the **lost update transaction isolation issue**.

Here is the corresponding figure:

[image: lost update]

And to quote the text accompanying the figure:

> A lost update occurs if two transactions both update a data item and
>   then the second transaction aborts, causing both changes to be lost.
>   This occurs in systems that don’t implement concurrency control, where
>   concurrent transactions aren’t isolated.

My interrogation relates to the above figure: why is the **Tx A**'s change lost considering the fact that the commit of **Tx A** occurs before the rollback of **Tx B**? (The numbers indicate the order of events).

Can someone please explain?

P.S. *I am quoting the Java Persistence with Hibernate Second Edition book published by Manning. (See: https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate-second-edition)*

**Edit**: The text I quoted above together with the figure are meant to demonstrate the lost update issue. So it assumes the database has little to no isolation, hence the lost update. What I fail to understand is the order of the operations on the figure.. In other words, if the commit occurs before the rollback, then where is the problem? The rollback should not be taken into account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on implementation of transaction logging system of each database. There are different types of such system and if you want to go deeper in the subject, you need to elaborate these things first.

Also, the answer depends on what transaction isolation level has been taken. Again, it depends not only on particular database, but on particular instructions that were used to update database. Some databases allow to set any isolation level, even if it can make data inconsistent in case of concurrent update or rollback.

So, as you didn't provide any details on particular implementation, I can guess that your abstract database uses snapshot isolation. That means, that before any data modification, of a row, or range of rows or whole table, a copy of that data was made. The copy is initial state of modifying data.

Normally a transaction cannot be started before another transaction has not been finished, that requirement is achieved by locks. But in your example that happened and one transaction successfully modified data and another transaction rolled back.

Any transaction that cannot be committed should return incompletely modified data to initial state. For transaction B that state doesn't have transaction A changes, because isolation level is snapshot. Some databases work differently, by the way, and do not make any snapshots of initial state before modification, but save only changes in transactional log and then apply them when transaction considered committed.

So, the answer is: because initial state of transaction B didn't have transaction A changes. And that in some way is correct: rollback should always get data back to the state when transaction started.

UPDATE:

How it would look like if we would implement depicted situation in abstract programming language?

```
function Update(rowNumber, data){
    initialState = getRowInitialState(rowNumber);  // ------- 1
    operationResult = updateRow(rowNumber, data);
    if (operationResult == success)
        commit(rowNumber);                        // ---------- 3
    else
        rollback(rowNumber, initialState)
}

function Delete(rowNumber){
    initialState = getRowInitialState(rowNumber);  // ---------- 2
    operationResult = deleteRow(rowNumber); // <--- cause some problems
    if (operationResult == success)
        commit(rowNumber);
    else
        rollback(rowNumber, initialState)          // -------- 4
}

Update(13, "aaaa");
Delete(13);
```

As you can see, rollback on Delete operation will reset data to initial state. Implying that there are no transaction log. Normally data wouldn't be really changed. Instead of that, in transaction log would be written information that some operation should be performed and some data should be changed. In this case, rollback really doesn't discard result of Update operation. Because the only thing it has to do is to remove record from transaction log. And if operation has succeeded, the changes from transaction log are applied to real data. But it looks like your abstract database does not have such mechanism. Or it illustrates access to transactionless database, which could be one of NoSQL databases. In this case there is no such log and synchronization should be performed on the client side.

Comment: Hi @cassandrad and thanks for your answer: the text I quoted together with the figure are meant to demonstrate the lost update issue. So it assumes the database has little to no isolation, hence the lost update. What I fail to understand is the order of the operations on the figure.. In other words, if the commit occurs before the rollback, then what is the problem?

Comment: I feel there is a disparity between the figure and the quoted text... What are your thoughts?

Comment: To be more accurate, if the commit occurs before the rollback, then the rollback should not be taken into account at all. Should it?

Comment: If rollback isn't taken into account, then it doesn't do its work. What do you expect when you are doing rollback? Of course, there could be some synchronization mechanisms, but your example clearly states that there are no such things. Normally, there shouldn't be any sync after rollback or at that moment, nor after commit or at that moment. Synchronization usually performed before any operation begins. Why rollback discarded changes of another commit? Look at updated section of my answer for illustration.

Comment: My comment about *rollback not being taken into account* was not put properly. Sorry. I should have said: the rollback does not affect the commit by TxA.

Comment: Thanks a lot: I am starting to understand now. The code sample and especially the lines that get the initial state are of particular interest. Can you just confirm that the initial state retrieved in `// ---------- 2` is the state of `D1` before either transactions start?

Comment: @balteo, yep, that's right! It is the only explanation for me. Normally data isn't changed when transaction begins at all, that's why there is no reason to save initial state of data. Usually the only thing that happens when transaction is rolled back is that command to update data gets cancelled. But your example does not provide any information on how data modification really works in your db. So, the only explanation is that there is initial state that saved at the beginning of any transaction.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for taking the time to put together this answer!